# Does a random selection disrupt an ordered one?

Tags: probability

I bought a container of 500 antacid tablets, which holds equal numbers of 4 different colors of tablets. Each night I take two tablets, paying no attention to their colors. My wife later also takes two, but selects them to have matching colors.

She believes that my random selection reduces her ability to get two matching tablets, as the bottle empties. True? How could she demonstrate this?

Comment: If you follow her method by selecting matching colors too, you'll surely have 4 tablets with 4 different colors on the last day (because there are an odd number of tablets of each color). If you don't, there's a chance you won't get stuck on the last day. So I think your original process (not paying attention) actually improves her chance of getting two matching tablets on the last day.

Comment: True, for the last day. But does my process reduce the total number of color pairs she can select, throughout the life of the bottle? If so, by what amount?

Comment: She will always be able to pick a pair of matching color until the last day because if there are more than 4 pills, at least 2 of them have the same color.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what she means by "random selection".

If the alternative to random selection is to select matching pairs like she does, then, as noted in the comments, you're actually improving her chances of always getting matching pairs: Since there's an odd number of each colour, she will always be able to pick a matching pair until there are only $4$ tablets left. If you were to also pick matching pairs, the last $4$ tablets would be sure to be of different colours, whereas if you pick randomly, there's a chance for her to get a matching pair on the last day.

On the other hand, you could deliberatly choose your tablets such that she'd get a matching pair on the last night. If this is the alternative to "random selection" she has in mind, then she's right, since if you select randomly she may or may not get a matching pair on the last night.